# Why do my browsers say my server's SSL certificate has expired but OpenSSL says it hasn't?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

In my nginx conf file, I have an ssl_certificate identified.  According to OpenSSL, the end date of that certificate is in the future.  When I access my site from a browser, it says that the certificate has expired.

It is possible I used the expired certificate previously, but I don't understand where the browser is getting it from now.  Any suggestions where I should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate has two fields - Valid From and Valid To. Check that both parameters are ok, i.e. Valid From is in the past and Valid To is in the future.

When you visit the site with the browser, it shows the lock icon either left to the URL in the address bar or in the status bar. Clicking on the lock icon will show you the certificate that the browser sees. Check that this certificate corresponds to the one you have in server config.

Comment: The start date is fine - in the past. The certificate the browser sees has different start and end dates than the one I expect to be served so it's a different certificate but I don't know why it isn't using the one I expect.

Comment: It looks like I was not correctly starting nginx with my current configuration. After stopping and starting it, I see the correct certificate. Thank you.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I also had problems with properly restarting nginx with changed config. Sending HUP signal doesn't seem to work right.